# Would like to get rid of std out when calling a script from another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am supposed to call script 2 from script 1 and script 2 calls script 3 within script 2. In script 3 there are some STDOUT statements which are being printed when I make a call to script 2 from script 1. If I call script 2 using script 1 *n* number of times the STDOUT statements from script 3 keep getting printed *n* times.

How do I get rid of this problem without making any changes to script 2 and script 3? I would like to make changes in my script 1 to resolve this problem. Please kindly help me.

In the below code I am calling `pri_000_table_truncate.ksh` script everytime and this script again makes calls to another script called `pri_000_functions.ksh` where the same message keeps getting printed everytime if I make calls from script 1 which is as posted below.

Sample Code:

```
if [[ ${PRI_TRNC1_FLG} = 'R' ]]
then
    echo
    echo "Truncating Table ${PRI_NZTBL1} of set $i..."
    echo "Calling truncate generic shell script for the table ${PRI_NZTBL1}..."
    echo
    ${PRI_EXE}/pri_000_table_truncate.ksh ${PRI_NZ_BATCH_DB} ${PRI_NZTBL1}

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo
        echo "Truncate Failed for Table ${PRI_NZTBL1}..."
        echo
        exit 1
    else
        echo
        echo "Successfully Truncated Table ${PRI_NZTBL1}..."
        echo
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I think I will be dizzy if I read first paragraph all at once : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output to `> /dev/null`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do stuff
# ...

# Call another script
./script1.sh $arg1 $arg2 > /dev/null
```

If you're calling a unix utility, some have the `-s` option for `--silent`, or something similar.

As the commenter before me said, it is very difficult to read the explanation of your problem (without getting dizzy), so these are just some general remarks.